# constant pool patching

Tags: jvm, java, .class-file

I was looking through the OpenJDK class file parser source and I came across something I've never heard of - Constant Pool Patching. What is this? I've read the JVM specification before but it didn't mention anything like this, and searching on Google failed to turn anything up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it simply, the patching procedure replaces constant pool entries at class parse time in order to handle JSR-229, which implements *invokedynamic*. It is used to rewrite UTF-8, class, and value (float, int, etc.) entries when loading *anonymous classes*.

For a primer on how *invokedynamic* is implemented, see http://blog.headius.com/2008/09/first-taste-of-invokedynamic.html